# What is the flow for svn update in this scenario?

Tags: svn

Ok I know that this command works, but I have a silly question which I have not been to able answer.

Let's say I have a svn repository with a file named  a.txt, and it has got a number in say X, User A  checks it out and than locally changes it to Y in a.txt, Now he wants to commit it, So before doing it he does SVN update, So ideally what should happen is that SVN update should throw a conflict because both of these files are different. But in my case SVN update runs and says no current changes between the repository and working copy.,

Can anyone tell me is my reasoning is correct? In my opinion this scenario is exactly similar to standard svn conflict between two users

Edit:
Looking at the answer of sharptooth, It is clear that my reasoning is incorrect, So can anyone please provide the flow overview of the svn update? i.e.If I have got R repo and W working copy, what does svn update look for while calculating diff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local working copy contains all the files in their original state for the current revision. These original files are stored in .svn folder. The size of .svn folder is in essence equal to the size of your project files. When you issue an update SVN client will update this .svn folder to latest revision, and then try to update all your working files. If some file is changed then it will try to merge the changes in the working file. If it cannot merge it will complain about the conflict. This happens if both the new revision and your working file have changed the same line in a file. You then have to resolve the conflict, bearing in mind what was old, what arrived new from repository, and your own changes.

Once you issue a commit, SVN client first checks if your working copy has most recent revision, and if it has sends to the server all differences between your working files and the files in .svn folder. If all goes well then it copies all different working files into the .svn folder, and so the .svn folder is in sync with the repository on the server.

Answer (score 2):

In SVN "checkout" is a client-only operation and a working copy change is also a client-only operation and the repository never knows about them. Since noone changed the repository copy of the file there's no grounds for a conflict. There would be a conflict if some user B committed a change to the same file between the moment user A last updated (or checked out) the file and the moment user A performs the update in question.

Answer (score 0):

'svn update' doesn't show a conflict because of the fact that first it let's the user override their local changes by default. That means it will conflict in a case when some other user has committed a different thing in the same place where you have changed the file locally, otherwise it won't find a conflict. Probably you are well aware that you can see your changes by running 'svn diff' even after update.